# Is it possible to connect an iPhone/iPad via WiFi Protected Setup (WPS)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, wifi

I was wondering if anyone know if it is possible to connect your iPhone/iPad to a router via WiFi Protected Setup (WPS)?

I would like to bypass entering my password on my iOS device and speed pairing similar to how printers can get on the router with a PIN or first attempt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot do this ([source](http://www.quora.com/iOS/Can-you-use-push-button-WPS-Wi-Fi-setup-with-the-iPhone-iPad)). You should strongly consider not using WPS anyway, as it has a number of [documented security issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup#Security). Apple has a page which [describes recommended router setup](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4199) for connecting an iOS device, which might help.

Comment: if WPS is the only option then it is better to use it then to leave the network wide open... but we can say that about all the security setups... You know the old saying "if there is a will there is a way".

Comment: @TheX WPS is *never* the *only* option. On any network that has WPS configured, there are other authentication mechanisms in place - WPS is just an available shortcut. While it may not be possible to disable WPS on some APs/routers, it's never enforced as the *only* authentication option.

Comment: Apple does support WPS on its airport line of routers, so the security risks seem worth the trade off for allowing printers to connect without typing a secure pass code or pass phrase onto the printer without benefit of a full keyboard.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. The security issues seem to refer to WPS being steadily enabled, but the only way I know WPS on wifi routers is that it can be manually enabled for a few minutes (it will automatically disable itself again afterwards), just so one device can quickly connect without the necessity to manually retype (and probably mistype several times) the password. With the alternative in mind, I'd say WPS can be the only option acceptable to end users; their default reaction when I have to re-type my wifi password on a new mobile device is usually to ask me to simply shorten or ...

Comment: ... or remove the wifi password because typing it is too cumbersome.

Comment: WPS connection of a device does not impact the security of the WPS WI-FI access point. While WPS is vulnerable using available software to attach the WPS access, the connection of a device to that network makes it no less secure. Newer devices circumvent the vulnerability by limiting the number of attempts to enter WPS passcodes and/or setting time limits between attempts that make the brute force method unlikely to succeed and/or they change the PWS passcode periodically. None of these methods make the brute force method totally unable to unlock the passcode, however, they can make it so diff

Comment: THat is such a typical Apple answer!  "We can't do that and  you shouldn't want to anyway."

Comment: @Iszi how ridiculous, of course WPS is sometimes the only option. I'm at a holiday cottage and the router password is missing.

Comment: @mjaggard Then contact the network administrator for the password. Or use mobile data instead of joining an unfamiliar network. Or maybe just take a holiday from the Internet entirely while you're out - it could do your mental health some good. It may even be that the WiFi password isn't missing. Your host might just not like visitors joining their network. Troy Hunt has a great post on his blog (sorry, too lazy to Google the link right now) about why he doesn't let guests on his WiFi, and the alternatives which are readily available to them.

Comment: They do let guests use the WiFi - as long as they're not Apple fanbois (because some previous guest has taken the password with them). And sadly I needed to work briefly on my work-provided iDevice (I would never waste such a quantity of money).